# $2\times 2$ matrices over complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this problem.
If $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix with complex entries, then $A$ is similar over $\Bbb C$ to a matrix of one of the two types
$$
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & 0\\
  0 & b\\
  \end{array} } \right],
$$
$$
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & 0 \\
   1 & a \\
  \end{array} } \right].
$$

Could you please tell me how to start? I have no idea! Thanks

Comment: Hint: use Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break into cases by the number of possible eigenvalues.

If $M$ is diagonal or has two distinct eigenvalues it is diagonalizable, so is similar to the first type. Otherwise there is only a single 1-dimensional eigenspace and it is similar to the second type.